# How would services like yammer be using xmpp? does xmpp cross paths with a queue?

Tags: xmpp, real-time, rabbitmq

How would services like yammer be using xmpp?  does xmpp cross paths with a queue? i.e. could one use rabbitmp instead of xmpp or are they completely different things?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the late answer, but late than never.

I am more of a XMPP developer and have little experience with rabbitmq but yes you can use rabbitmq instead of XMPP if your application needs are satisfied by rabbitmq.

XMPP have exhaustive implementation of Multi-User Chat and PubSub which can be used if rabbitmq alone is not enough to satisfy your application need.

Can you expand "does xmpp cross paths with a queue"??